# Is ActiveSupport::MessageVerifier from Rails 3.2 production-ready?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2, release, production-environment, activesupport

Part of our team is working to upgrade our large codebase from Rails 3.2 to 4.2.

Before that is finished, I'd already like to use `ActiveSupport::MessageVerifier` for a new feature. The release notes for 4.1 [included them](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/4_1_release_notes.html#message-verifiers) so I naturally assumed they were introduced in 4.1.

I was trying to estimate the effort of backporting `ActiveSupport::MessageVerifier` to Rails 3. Going through [its history](https://github.com/rails/rails/commits/master/activesupport/lib/active_support/message_verifier.rb), I discovered that the [original commit](https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/d460c9a25560f43e7c3789abadf7b455053eb686) has been included in Rails core since 2.3.0.

Now I wonder:

**Is it safe to use the [message verifier shipped in 3.2](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/3-2-stable/activesupport/lib/active_support/message_verifier.rb) in production?**

Answer (score 3):

What's new in 4.1 is easy access to named verifiers that use `secret_key_base`.  `ActiveSupport::MessageVerifier` has been used for signed cookies since 2.3.6 (here's the [commit](https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/0200e20f148c96afceeebc4da7b5985643f9f707) that added it)  so I would definitely consider it production ready.

Comment: Well, that clears it up. Thanks. The release notes should be more specific in this regard.